# Point-wise bound implies norm bound

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be a Banach spaces, and $T,G : X^* \to Y^*$ be bounded operators.

If for every $f\in X^*$ we have the point-wise bound $$Tf(x)\leq Gf(x)$$
for $Tf = T(f) \in Y^*$, and $Gf = G(f) \in Y^*$, then can we conclude that $$\|Tf\|_{Y^*}\leq\|Gf\|_{Y^*}\quad ?$$

If it's not possible, can we get 
$$\|Tf\|_{Y^*}\leq K\|Gf\|_{Y^*}\quad ?$$
for some constant $K$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$Tf(x)\leq Gf(x)$ implies $Gf(-x)=-Gf(x)\leq Tf(-x)$, we deduce that $Tf(-x)=Gf(-x)$ since we have also $Tf(-x)\leq Gf(-x)$ for every $x$. This implies that  $Tf=Gf$.

Comment: Correct answer, wrong question. I'll try to re-frame it and ask it later. Thanks though